# How to get result from 1st task then pass it to 2nd task using ContinueWith in a loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

So here's what I'm doing:

```
var resultObj = GetFirstResultAsync()
     .ContinueWith(t => GetSecondResultAsync(resultObj))
     .Wait();
```

Essentially telling me that I can't use the variable before it's even declared, which I get hence the question I posted. How do I do this?

Here's my goal, I have a list `resultObj` then on that list I will loop through the Id's to get an array of my another list that I want `GetSecondResultAsync` kinda drilling down on the list, I wanted to use async since it will be using `HttpClient` to get the data.

Comment: It defeats the purpose of writing asynchronous code when you're just going to synchronously block at the end of the operation.

Comment: t.Result has what you need

Comment: would this be a good solution so I can avoid the "too many request error"? thanks @fahadash

Comment: Avoid it altogether and just use `var resultObj = await GetFirstResultAsync(); await GetSecondResultAsync(resultObj);` Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I am casting a reopen vote because the question [linked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912733/how-to-continuewith-another-function-with-result-from-previous-task-when-using-t) is about invoking a continuation function on the UI thread, while this question is about creating a new task that represents the result of the continuation function. The two questions are related, but not identical IMHO.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to convert a Task<TDerived> to a Task<TBase>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530099/how-to-convert-a-tasktderived-to-a-tasktbase)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a continuation `Task` that has a result of different type than the first task, with [`ContinueWith`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith), is not trivial. You have to use the [`Unwrap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) method in order to flatten the resulting `Task<Task<MySecondResult>>`, handle carefully the failure and cancellation cases, and [specify explicitly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) the `TaskScheduler` that will execute the continuation:

```
Task<MySecondResult> task = GetFirstResultAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<MySecondResult> tcs = new();
        tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    if (t.IsCanceled)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<MySecondResult> tcs = new();
        tcs.SetCanceled(new TaskCanceledException(t).CancellationToken);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    return GetSecondResultAsync(t.Result);
}, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
```

This is quite cumbersome. You don't want to have code like this appear frequently in your application code. You can either encapsulate this functionality in an extension method, like the `Then`/`ContinueWithResult` extension method requested in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692) GitHub proposal, or use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) instead of the `ContinueWith`. Async/await is composable, so you can write a third `async` method that combines the `GetFirstResultAsync` and the `GetSecondResultAsync` to one:

```
async Task<MySecondResult> GetSecondAfterFirstAsync()
{
    MyFirstResult result = await GetFirstResultAsync();
    return await GetSecondResultAsync(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the result by changing the ContinueWith statement to t.Result. Something like:

```
var resultObj = GetFirstResultAsync()
 .ContinueWith(t => GetSecondResultAsync(t.Result));
```

I haven't tested the code.

The first run thread will return a "Task". Which you will have to access by Task.Result. This is what you will have to use.

Edit: As @fahadash stated, "wait()" should not be used. Use "await" instead.

Comment: Let me try this but thank you @KampfFussel

Comment: The correct way would be to not call `Wait()`, but keep the resultObj as task, and whenever in your code you are ready to use the result, use `await resultObj`

Comment: @fahadash that seemed to work, without the wait, any ideas how I can loop through it without hitting 429 (too many request) ? within the "continueWith" like this : ContinueWith(t=> while (true) {GetSecondResultAsync(t.result.id)}

Comment: @PinoyDev That sounds like a separate question than about `Task<T>` You seem to be sending too many requests in a small amount of time and server is throttling you. If you are running tasks in a parallel, be sure to set throttle on your end to limit them to certain number at a time

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @fahadash. I updated my answer accordingly.